# Regex negative match query

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I've got a regex issue, I'm trying to ignore just the number '41', I want 4, 1, 14 etc to all match.

I've got this `[^\b41\b]` which is effectively what I want but this also ignores all single iterations of the values 1 and 4.

As an example, this matches "41", but I want it to NOT match:
\b41\b

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
\b(?!41\b)(\d+)
```

The `(?!...)` construct is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) so this means: find a word boundary that is *not* followed by "41" and capture a sequence of digits after it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative [look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) to exclude `41`:

```
/\b(?!41\b)\d+\b/
```

This regular expression is to be interpreted as: At any word boundary `\b`, if it is not followed by `41\b` (`(?!41\b)`), match one or more digits that are followed by a word boundary.

Or the same with a negative [look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
/\b\d+\b(?<!\b41)/
```

This regular expression is to be interpreted as: Match one or more digits that are surrounded by word boundaries, but only if the substring at the end of the match is not preceded by `\b41` (`(?<!\b41)`).

Or can even use just basic syntax:

```
/\b(\d|[0-35-9]\d|\d[02-9]|\d{3,})\b/
```

This matches only sequences of digits surrounded by word boundaries of either:

- one single digit
- two digits that do not have a `4` at the first position or not a `1` at the second position
- three or more digits

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the question "[Regular expression that doesn’t contain certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string/)", so I'll repeat my answer from there:

```
^((?!41).)*$
```

This will work for an arbitrary string, not just 41. See [my response there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string/2387072#2387072) for an explanation.