# Filter Git log for commits that don't contain a specific word

Tags: git

How can I filter git logs for commits that don't contain a specific word?

I've looked at regexp sites, and tried some cases without success in Git Bash.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `git log --grep="<your string>"` combined with the `--invert-grep` parameter to invert the search criteria (as of Git for Windows 2.6.2).

### Example:

Find commits where the commit message **contains** the string `foo`:

`git log --grep="foo"`

Find commits where the commit message **does not contain** the string `foo`:

`git log --invert-grep --grep="foo"`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [by Claudiu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/717659)

> In general it's a pain to write a regular expression not containing a particular string. We had to do this for models of computation - you take an NFA, which is easy enough to define, and then reduce it to a regular expression. The expression for things not containing "cat" was about 80 characters long.

and you can do it in inverse, not elegant, but working way

`git log ... | grep -v "someword"`

PS - negation in RE is ^ prefix, it (prefix usage) may want -E (extended regexp) for `git log`, but defining *negated word* **as word** for regexp is just real nightmare

Answer (score 0):

You can only search *commit messages* this way, which is done by submitting code using the `-m` flag in your check-in. Example:

```
commit -m "message describing awesome code changes"
```

This will save the message `"message describing awesome code changes"` in the log, meaning that a search for the word `awesome`, as an example, will now return this as a result.

Is it possible that the phrase/word/message you are searching for has never been included in a commit message?

Comment: I think I should call `git log --grep=specificword` but this display commit messages with `specificword` howevere I want a log the commit messages doesn't contain `specificword`.