# Regex: Match word not containing

Tags: regex

I have the following words:

```
EFI Internal Shell
EFI Hard Drive
EFI Drive
```

I want to match words that contain EFI but not containing Drive. So only the top word (EFI Internal Shell) should match.

How can this be done in regex?

I looked through SO and none of the answers were able to get me on the right track.

For example: [Regular expression that doesn't contain certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string) says to use `^((?!my string).)*$` but that [didn't work](https://regex101.com/r/aF6hT1/1). Even to match any string not containing Drive.

Any tips?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your `^((?!Drive).)*$` did not work at all because you tested against a multiline input.

You should use `/m` modifier to see [what the regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/aF6hT1/2). It just matches lines that do not contain `Drive`, but that *tempered greedy token* does not check if `EFI` is inside the string.

Actually, the `$` anchor is redundant here since `.*` matches any zero or more characters other than line break characters. You may simply remove it from your pattern.

(**NOTE**: In .NET, you will need to use `[^\r\n]*` instead of `.*` since `.` in a .NET pattern matches any char but a newline, LF, char, and matches all other line break chars, like a carriage return, CR, etc.).

Use something like

```
^(?!.*Drive).*EFI.*
```

Or, if you need to only fail the match if a `Drive` is present as a **whole word**:

```
^(?!.*\bDrive\b).*EFI.*
```

Or, if there are more words you want to signal the failure with:

```
^(?!.*(?:Drive|SomethingElse)).*EFI.*
^(?!.*\b(?:Drive|SomethingElse)\b).*EFI.*
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aK6sB5/1)

Here,

- `^` - matches start of string
- `(?!.*Drive)` - makes sure there is no "Drive" in the string (so, `Drives` are NOT allowed)
- `(?!.*\bDrive\b)` - makes sure there is no "Drive" as a *whole word* in the string (so, `Drives` are allowed)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `EFI` - an`EFI` substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

If your string has newlines, either use a `/s` dotall modifier or replace `.` with `[\s\S]`.