# Regex for disallowing characters in filename

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to build a regex that *disallows* certain characters in a `String` in an Android application. That is, if any of the characters are *not* in a set of allowed characters, I should be able to know. My *allowed* characters are:

```
"a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ_ -"
```

The user types in a name which I want to check. My current take on this is:

```
filename.matches("^((?![a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ_ -]).)*$");
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2387072/1139324) answer. This regex returns `false` for all input, except if *all* characters are disallowed, which is not what I want. I also tried a simpler regex

```
filename.matches("([^a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ_ -])");
```

to try to match anything *not* in the capturing group, but this did not work as intended either.

What am I missing? Are there any quirks or special things in the Java regex engine in this particular case?

#### Examples

None of the regexes provided gives the desired result. Consider these examples. When the string contains both accepted and unaccepted characters, it fails to produce the proper result. The result is the same in Python. When pasting the two regexes below into https://regex101.com/, however, the latter seems to work as expected. It does not in reality though. I also tried adding capturing groups (i.e. parantheses) to the regexes, but to no avail.

```
String foo1 = "this_is_a_filename";
String foo2 = "this%is%not%a%filename";
String foo3 = "%+!?";

String regex1 = "^[^a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ_ -]+$";
String regex2 = "[^a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ_ -]+";

boolean isMatch;

isMatch = foo1.matches(regex1); // false, ok
isMatch = foo2.matches(regex1); // false, should be true
isMatch = foo3.matches(regex1); // true, ok

isMatch = foo1.matches(regex2); // false, ok
isMatch = foo2.matches(regex2); // false, should be true
isMatch = foo3.matches(regex2); // true, ok
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a regex to match a character that is not valid. That's the negation of the set of allowed chars: `[^a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ_ -]`

And use [Matcher#find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) method:

> public boolean find() 
>   Attempts to find the next subsequence of the
>   input sequence that matches the pattern. 
>   Returns: true if, and only if, a subsequence of the input sequence matches this matcher's pattern

Example:

```
String foo1 = "this_is_a_filename";
String foo2 = "this%is%not%a%filename";
String foo3 = "%+!?";

String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ_ -]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
System.out.println("Foo1: " + p.matcher(foo1).find());
System.out.println("Foo2: " + p.matcher(foo2).find());
System.out.println("Foo3: " + p.matcher(foo3).find());
```

Output:

```
Foo1: false
Foo2: true
Foo3: true
```

Ideone demo: https://ideone.com/S36DYF

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `String#matches` as it attempts to match full input. Use this string in `Pattern` and `Matcher` APIs:

```
String regex = "[\\wæøåÆØÅ -]"; 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find())
    System.out.println("Input has at least one valid char");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP7kT6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your have to use full string match using ^ and $ in the two end of the string
as follows:
filename.matches("^[^a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ_ -]+$");

Comment: Well, I suppose you could use the `^` and `$` anchors, but it should not matter in this case as far as I am aware. I updated my post with some examples of what worked and what didn't.