# How to use regex with not ^ and capture groups?

Tags: regex

How do I use the Not operator ^ with the capture groups in regex.

Example:
I have two URLs coming in http://api.example.com and http://example.com

How would I make a capture group on all URLs that do not contain `api`.

How I thought this would look is `var notAPI = /(^api)/;`

Comment: Use `indexOf`. `if (url.indexOf('api')) === -1` or `!/api/.test(url)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression that doesn't contain certain string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex only has negative lookaheads and lookbehinds. Their spirit is: you only look, you don't move forward.

This is a negative lookahead:

```
(?!nomatch)
```

And this is a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!nomatch)
```

You can incorporate these lookarounds into your regex like this:

```
var notAPI = /^((?!api).)*$/;
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2387072/4464702) - it also explains how it works.

Comment: Yup that was it.  I hardly know how to frame this question.  Super new to regex.  I need to hit the books.