# Bash script : in file replace characters with 'X" between two given strings using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

```
file=mylog.log
search_str="&Name="
end_str="&"
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X'"$end_str"']/\1X/; ta' "$file"

Ex 1:
something&Name=JASON&else
to
something&Name=XXXXX&else
```

And actually, my current sed command works fine when instead of a '"$end_str"' if I use '&' character... Like this :

```
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta' "$file"
```

So, to summariz, it, after ^X if a single character comes than my given sed command works fine... But the same command does not work, if instead of character, i use a string...

```
For example, my sed command won't work in this case :
end_str="\%26"
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X'"$end_str"']/\1X/; ta' "$file"
```

Eg:

```
something&Name=JASON_MATTHEW_DONALD%26else
TO
something&Name=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26else
```

Eg:2

```
something&Name=JASON%26else
TO
something&Name=XXXXX%26else
```

Please let me know

Comment: In `sed`, `[ ]` is a character class, not a string. It means any single character within `[ ]`. With the `^` prefix, it means any single character that is not in `[ ]`.

Comment: @alvits Thanks Alvits... So, instead of [] what i should use?

Comment: @PuneetJain: Can you summarise your final input and expected output? It is not clear exactly as of now.

Comment: ``
    `something&Name=JASON%26else`   

    `TO`   

    `something&Name=XXXXX%26else`   

``

Answer (score 0):

Place your string variable outside the character class and capture it to check for further substitutions:

```
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X](.*'"$end_str"')/\1X\2/; ta' "$file"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn;t worked.It replaced the & with X and eaten many characters in between... May be fine tune a little bit the above sed command?

Comment: Try to escape the `&`: `\&`. Does it work with `\%26` ?

Comment: I tried with \%26. Didn't worked... Single character & works with my orif=ginal sed command, so I am not worried about it... but with \%26, mine and your sed command didn't worked...any pointers?

Comment: I tested with your sample inputs (single or multiple characters), it's working with GNU sed. What's your OS? your sed version?

Comment: `can u try this if`
`search_str="\%3dName="`  
`end_str="\%26"`
    
`something%3dName=JASON%MATTHEW%2DONALD%26else`  
`TO`  
`something%3dName=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26else`

Comment: That's my input with this command.

Comment: what is the output ?

Comment: `something%3dName=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26else`|

Comment: OS: Windows ..... sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2  
I am not sure why you sed command not perfactly working in my setup... Do you think we should tweak the command a little bit for my OS/GNU/SED

Comment: If you're under Windows, it might be carriage return in your input file that you can remove with `tr -d '\r' < input.log > newinput.log`

Answer (score 0):

If the number of `X` doesn't matter you can simplify it to:

```
search="Name"
sed "s/$search=[^&]*/$search=XXX/" input.file
```

This assumes that `$search` won't contain special characters which have a meaning in `sed's` regex syntax. If special characters can be a problem you need to prepare the `$search` variable, as explained here: [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/171318)

Comment: Unfortunately number of X does matter... ::-(

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because I need to replace the characters with two strings, with equal number of X. See my edited question example 1 and 2

Comment: I'm just asking why. I mean why do you need to preserve the length of the user name?

Comment: Because other than names, i need to replace passwords and some other fields.. for which i need to know how many characters i am replacing

Comment: That's exactly my point. When you replace passwords you *don't* want to preserve the length. Because the length is already a *very* valuable information to brute force a password. Replace all passwords by tree *. That's fine.

Comment: PS: Sending passwords in plain text via an url is another point, but that's off-topic here.

Comment: No.. because... for other fields we receive from clients, some sensitive info, we need to mask it by X (euall number of X) so that we can debug later as to how many bytes were sent for a field

Answer (score 0):

I insist on the point that keeping the length of passwords in logs is a very bad idea (security wise).

Having said that:

First, a character list `[...]` is not the right tool to match an string. For that we need to use an alternating value `(...|...)`.

```
end_str="(&|%26)"
```

But it is quite difficult to express a "not a string" in regex.

```
not_end_str="([^&]|[^%]|%[^2]|%2[^6])"
```

Using all that we may build a pure bash solution (maybe not fast, but works).
It prints to stdout to show how it works.
Redirect to a file to store the result.

```
file=mylog.log
search_str="&Name="
end_str="(&|%26)"                       # write end_str as an alternate value.
not_end_str="([^&]|[^%]|%[^2]|%2[^6])"  # regex negate end_string.

# Build a regex that split each part of the text.
myreg="(.*${search_str}X*)(${not_end_str}*)([&%].*)"

while IFS=$'\n' read line; do
    [[ $line =~ $myreg ]]
    len=$((${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}-2))          # do not count [0] and last.
    arr=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")            # remove [0] and last.
    arr[1]=${arr[1]//?/X}                   # Replace name with "X"'s.
    arr[2]=''                               # Clear not_end_str match
    printf '%s' "${arr[@]}"; echo           # Print modified line.
done <"$file"
```

Further reading:

- [Regular expression to match line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)
- [Regular expression that doesn't contain certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string)