# RegEx Expression for Eclipse that searches for all items that have not been dealt with

Tags: regex, eclipse, jsp, sql-injection

To help stop SQL Injection attacks, I am going through about 2000 parameter requests in my code to validate them. I validate them by determining what type of value (e.g. integer, double) they should return and then applying a function to them to sanitize the value.

Any requests I have dealt with look like this

```
*SecurityIssues.*(request.getParameter
```

where * signifies any number of characters on the same line.

What RegExp expression can I use in the Eclipse search (CTRL+H) which will help me search for all the ones I have not yet dealt with, i.e. all the times that the text request.getParameter appears when it is **not** preceded by the word SecurityIssues?

#### Examples for matches

The regular expression should match each of the following e.g.

```
int companyNo = StringFunctions.StringToInt(request.getParameter("COMPANY_NO‌​"))
double percentage = StringFunctions.StringToDouble(request.getParameter("MARKETSHARE"))
int c = request.getParameter("DUMMY")
```

But should not match:

```
int companyNo = SecurityIssues.StringToIntCompany(request.getParameter("COMP‌​ANY_NO"))
```

Comment: Give just one or two example values of what the regular expression should match. And `.*` matches anything (also `request.getParameter`), so maybe consider `.*?` (reluctant).

Comment: e.g. it should NOT match `int companyNo = SecurityIssues.StringToIntCompany(request.getParameter("COMPANY_NO"))` but it should match `int companyNo = StringFunctions.StringToInt(request.getParameter("COMPANY_NO"))`

Comment: Are there other functions it should match, like `StringToDouble` etc.?

Comment: Yes, also places where there is no function at all e.g. `int c = request.getParameter("DUMMY")` (Have to leave office now, will update tomorrow.)

Comment: Please see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With inspiration and the links provided by @michaeak (thank you), as well as testing in https://regex101.com/ I appear to have found the answer:

```
^((?!SecurityIssues).)*(request\.getParameter)
```

The advantage of this answer is that I can blacklist the word SecurityIssues, as opposed to having to whitelist the formats that I do want.

Note, that it is relatively slow, and also slowed down my computer a lot when performing the search.

Comment: This one works, but the `^` at the beginning is not essential. And the `*` in the middle could lead to ommit true matches. I think it should be appended by `?`. Actually I was trying this one as well, but also to match the `=` character. But I did not understand the `^` was just to mark the beginning of the match ...

Comment: In line with how I understand StackOverflow protocol, this answer has been marked as the correct answer for the following reason: this answer was the first answer to answer the question - in that the question was looking for blacklisting a certain word rather than whitelisting certain words. Although the original answer given by @michaeak did contribute greatly to reaching this answer.  (That answer has now been updated with a possibly improved version of the accepted answer.)  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Try e.g.

```
=\s*?((?!SecurityIssues).)*?(request\.getParameter)\(
```

### Notes

Paranthesis `(` or `)` are special characters for group matching. They need to be escaped with `\`.
If `.*` will match anything, also characters that you don't want it to match. So `.*?` will prevent it from matching anything (reluctant). This can be helpful if after the wildcard other items need to match.

There is a tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html , I think all of these should be available in eclipse. You can then deal with generic replacement also.

### Problem

From reading [Regular expression that doesn't contain certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string) and [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) it seems quite difficult to create a regex matching anything but not to contain a certain word.

Comment: without a closing parenthesis, eclipse says "unclosed group near index 48). Also I would need to catch e.g. StringToDouble as well as StringToInt and also I would need to catch places where there is no function there as well e.g. int c=request.getParameter

Comment: Sorry, the marking as code was gong, so the `\\` disappeared. Also made it possible to have multiple functions match.

Comment: This looks great - it is just that I do not know the names of all the functions in advance, and I would need something more generic...